# Symfony json schema validation: no html tags

Tags: php, json, symfony, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How to create base requirement for all inputs using [Json Schema](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema) in Symfony project. For example I have multiple schemas, but none of the properties that are `"type": "string"` should accept HTML tags as an input?? There probably should be some Regex rule. However I need to find way to make it base validation rule for all inputs in validation method, without changing each schema files

```
public function check($jsonData, $schemaFilePath){
    $path = $this->fileLocator->locate($schemaFilePath);

    $schema = (object)['$ref' => 'file://' . $path];

    $this->validator->validate($jsonData, $schema);

    if($this->validator->isValid()){
        return null;
    }else{
        return $this->validator->getErrors();
    }
}
```

Hope my question is clear. let me know if i can add more details

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:

- there is no way in json schema to define such "base requirement"
- it is not possible to validate html with regex. Even your best effort would yield only partially working result, so your regex would provide false negatives and also false positives

I think it would be better to move this validation to the application level and use an appropriate HTML parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use JSON schema Bundle ( third party ) which may come with validator like :

https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

https://github.com/HadesArchitect/JsonSchemaBundle